# Multiple error-messages for polymer paper-input, depending on validation result

Tags: validation, polymer

I want to use the standard paper-input error validation

```
<paper-input label="Amount" value="{{amount}}" required error-message="Required OR Must be numeric ???" pattern="\d{3,}"></paper-input>
```

In case the input is empty, I want the error-message 'Required!'.
In case the input is not numeric, I want the error-message 'Must be numeric!'.

What is the best way to achieve that?